# makeindex: nomencl.ist unknown specifiers lethead_prefix, lethead_suffix

Tags: makeindex

When I run `makeindex` on a large (book-length) document (I'll call it `doc` here) that uses documentclass `memoir` and includes...

```
\makenomenclature
\makeindex[names]
\makeindex
```

... I'm seeing the following in the document's `.ilg`:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2019] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist........
** Input style error (file = /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist, line = 36):
   -- Unknown specifier lethead_prefix.
** Input style error (file = /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist, line = 37):
   -- Unknown specifier lethead_suffix.
** Input style error (file = /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist, line = 38):
   -- Unknown specifier lethead_flag.
....done (12 attributes redefined, 3 ignored).
Scanning input file doc.nlo....done (205 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries.....done (1532 comparisons).
Generating output file doc.nls....done (213 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in doc.nls.
Transcript written in doc.ilg.
```

The *only* `nomencl.ist` file on my system is the indicated one from the TeXLive 2019 distribution.

What's wrong?

**Added: a MWE**

Here's a small example, without needing any `nomencl.cfg`, to generate the "errors":

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[refpage,norefeq,intoc,english,nocfg]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Index of Notation}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

A \emph{map} $f\colon X \to Y$%
\nomenclature{$f \colon X \to Y$}{map from $X$ to $Y$}%
consists of \dots.

\backmatter

\printnomenclature[3.5cm]

\end{document}
```

In this case, the `.ilg` is:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2019] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist........
** Input style error (file = /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist, line = 36):
   -- Unknown specifier lethead_prefix.
** Input style error (file = /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist, line = 37):
   -- Unknown specifier lethead_suffix.
** Input style error (file = /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist, line = 38):
   -- Unknown specifier lethead_flag.
....done (12 attributes redefined, 3 ignored).
Scanning input file nom.nlo....done (1 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries...done (0 comparisons).
Generating output file nom.nls....done (6 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in nom.nls.
Transcript written in nom.ilg.
```

*Note:* Since no entries were rejected and there were no warnings, why am I asking about this? Because my document is now generating strange error messages `mathit allowed only in math mode` during processing of `doc.ind` whose cause I cannot trace. I ask about that separately: [Indexing error: \mathit allowed only in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528504/6865).

Comment: Can you please make a small example?

Comment: Anyway, the “errors” about `lethead...` are actually innocuous warnings.

Comment: @egreg : Good to have that innocuousness confirmed. (l'm desperately pursuing all leads, however unpromising, in my investigation of the `mathit allowed only in math mod` index processing error.)

Comment: These `lethead_...` were the old names for the current `heading_...` options, and are kept in makeindex style files for compatibility with older versions of makeindex. Though this is probably useless nowadays: I couldn't dig up a version of makeindex that uses the `lethead_...` names, so I guess it should be a couple of decades old...

Answer (score 1):

In the comments Phelype Oleinik already wrote:

> These `lethead_...` were the old names for the current `heading_...`
> options, and are kept in makeindex style files for compatibility with
> older versions of makeindex.

When looking into the `nomencl.ist` file (in TeX Live 2022), it explicitly states that:

```
%% The next lines will produce some warnings when
%% running Makeindex as they try to cover two different
%% versions of the program:
lethead_prefix "\\nomgroup{"
lethead_suffix "}"
lethead_flag   1
heading_prefix "\\nomgroup{"
heading_suffix "}"
headings_flag  1
```

Thus, just ignore those "errors".