# Indexing error: \mathit allowed only in math mode

Tags: indexing, makeindex

I’m looking for any possible clues in trying to track down a cause for the following error while writing or processing the `.ind` file for a `memoir` class document (using `latexmk` with `pdflatex`):

```
\mathit allowed only in math mode
```

This is occurring, in the first instance with `.ind` entry

```
\item \idxmark{Urysohn Metrization Theorem}, \hyperpage{506}, 
    \mainref{580}
```

The function `\mainref` is defined as:

```
\newcommand{\mainref}[1]{\textbf{\emph{\hyperpage{#1}}}}
```

But the error occurs even if I change `\mainref` to: `\newcommand{\mainref}[1]{#1}`

The log shows:

```
./book.ind:1772: LaTeX Error: \mathit allowed only in math mode.

 ...                                              

l.1772 \item \idxmark{Urysohn Metrization Theorem}
                                                  , \hyperpage{502},
```

The preamble invokes `hyperref` as follows:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,
  bookmarksnumbered,
  breaklinks=true,
  colorlinks, citecolor=red, filecolor=black, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue,
  linktocpage=true,linktoc=all, %
}
```

The portion of `doc.ind` around the cited line is:

```
\item \idxmark{upper semicontinuous map}, \hyperpage{317}, 
        \hyperpage{497}
\item \idxmark{Urysohn Metrization Theorem}, \hyperpage{502}, 
        \mainref{578}
\item \idxmark{Urysohn's Lemma}, \hyperpage{200}, \hyperpage{577}, 
        \mainref{577}, \hyperpage{578}
\item \idxmark{usual ordering}, \hyperpage{12--13}
```

And the end of `book.idx` is:

```
\indexentry{Urysohn's Lemma|mainref}{585}
\indexentry{Urysohn's Lemma|hyperpage}{585}
\indexentry{Urysohn's Lemma|)hyperpage}{586}
\indexentry{Tietze Extension Theorem|mainref}{586}
\indexentry{normal space!and Tietze Extension Theorem|hyperpage}{586}
\indexentry{normal space|)hyperpage}{586}
\indexentry{Urysohn Metrization Theorem|mainref}{586}
```

The document’s `.ist` file is:

```
item_0  "\n\\item \\idxmark{"
delim_0 "}, "
% not forgetting the subitem case
item_x1 "} \n \\subitem "
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\medskip\\hfill\\large\\textsf{\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}}\\hfill}\\medskip\\nopagebreak\n"
```

where `\idxmark` is defined in my preamble by:

```
\providecommand\gobbleone[1]{}
\newcommand{\idxmark}[1]{{\let\gobbleone\relax\markboth{\sffamily\bfseries#1}{\sffamily\bfseries#1}}#1}
```

The purpose of `\idxmark` is to cause the header on each Index page to show the first and last entries on the page (except for the first page).

If I comment out the `\index` entries for that “Urysohn Metrization Theorem”, then the same error occurs for other entries or subentries.

I can (awkwardly) work around the error by ignoring it and processing the source once more with `pdflatex`, but clearly something is wrong.

In case it helps, the index entry in question appears on the final page of output, shown here:

[image: End of index includes entry causing error]

**Likely resolution:**

The error arises from my improper use of the `repeatindex` package, in that I did not modify index entries by causing index entries to be created in the form `\item [Main Item A], 1, 3, 6  )`. And that can be accomplished by using `makeindex -s repeatindex`, that is, by using the file `repeatindex.ist` that is part of the `repeatindex` package. But this may conflict with my existing custom `.ist` file shown above. I have deferred asking about that to [How modify custom .ist to incorporate repeatindex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528520/how-modify-custom-ist-to-incorporate-repeatindex).

**I apologize** for not yet providing a complete, minimal working example for reproducing the error, but I think some clue might help me devise such. The document in question is of book length, with a complex source structure that includes multiple style files constituting the preamble.

Comment: can't say much without an example, but is the error you show the first error or did an earlier error (eg from a mis-placed `^`) start an unexpected math mode somewhere

Comment: Is there a page break around this place?

Comment: add \tracingmacros=1 a bit before the index entry and then show in the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I'm not seeng any page break around the `\index` entry in source or in the corresponding output.

Comment: well there is a column break. Where are the dots from?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The dots at the top of the index column come from package `repeatindex`. They occur whenever a main entry is continued from the end of one page to the next or from the end of one column to the next. Many pages of the (long) index get such dots, and without errors when the entries around them are being processed.

Comment: Aha! Eliminating use of `repeatindex` eliminates the error. But the error is something that has occurred only within the past several weeks. The `repeatindex` package is old. This suggests some recent change in `latex` or `memoir` or some other package I'm using is causing `repeatindex` no longer to work without complaint.

Comment: The error line you show contains the page number 502; the portion of the `.idx` file is for page 578; and the index page image you include shows pages 508 and 576.  At least the output page doesn't agree with the error lines and the example selection.  Simple question: did you remove the old `.idx` and `.ind` files before rerunning?

Comment: @murray repeatindex messes around with afterpage and changes the output routine. Lots of thing can fail here, and lots of things can be the cause - even a simple index entry more that changed the order. As I said you could add \tracingmacros to investigate, but from your output and the index entries it doesn't look as if you actually used repeatindex as intended - you only added odd dots in some places.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I did not explicitly add anything in the source to insert those dots. So far as I know, they were all added automatically by `repeatindex` . But I see that I should be modifying the latexmk so as to use the form `makeindex -s repeatindex  file`, which I had not done. I'll see if that helps. The question remains: why *now* is the error arising, whereas it never did earlier in time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because: OP added a likely resolution to the question and deferred asking about that to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528520/6865

Comment: I'm voting as well to close the question, but would like to point out that the error message is triggered by the line "`\indexentry{Urysohn's Lemma|)hyperpage}{586}`", where the `|)` is interpreted as `\)`, which is indeed the closer for inline math.

Comment: Yes, appropriate to close.