# How modify custom .ist to incorporate repeatindex

Tags: indexing, makeindex

Documentation for the `repeatindex` package says to use

```
makeindex -s repeatindex file
```

(or otherwise enclose each item in square-brackets), but I'm already using

```
makeindex -s file.ist
```

where `file.ist` is

```
item_0  "\n\\item \\idxmark{"
delim_0 "}, "
% not forgetting the subitem case
item_x1 "} \n \\subitem "
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\medskip\\hfill\\large\\textsf{\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}}\\hfill}\\medskip\\nopagebreak\n"
```

and the command `\idxmark` is defined in `file`s preamble by:

```
\newcommand{\idxmark}[1]{{\let\gobbleone\relax\markboth{\sffamily\bfseries#1}{\sffamily\bfseries#1}}#1}
\providecommand\gobbleone[1]{}
```

The purpose of `\idxmark` is to display in the header on each Index page the first and last entries on that page (except for the first page).

How do I modify my `.ist`, or the `\idxmark` command, so as to satisfy the requirements for `repeatindex`?

(My difficulty is that I don't understand the syntax and semantics of the `.ist` file!)

Here is a (nearly) MWE to show the problem and and to test proposed fixes to the `.ist` shown above:

```
%% File file.tex
\documentclass{memoir}

%% LANGUAGES & FONTS
\RequirePackage[russian,french,ngerman,polish,main=english]{babel}%
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}

%% LAYOUT
\RequirePackage{multicol}

%% UTILITIES
\RequirePackage{calc}

%%%%%%%% BEGIN STYLE %%%%%%%%
%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
\setstocksize{11in}{8.5in}
% entire typeblock is centered on stock
\setpagecc{55.25pc}{38pc}{*}
\settypeblocksize{45pc}{28pc}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{*}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

%% PAGE STYLES (headers & footers)
\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{mypage} 
\makeheadrule{mypage}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeevenhead{mypage}{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}{}{\bfseries\sffamily\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{mypage}{\bfseries\sffamily\rightmark}{}{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage} 
\addtopsmarks{mypage}{}{%
  % insert "Chapter\space" & "Section\space" if desired as 4th argument:
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{}{\enspace} 
  \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{\enspace}
}
% daleif:
\makepsmarks{mypage}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{}{\enspace} % use both not left
  \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{\enspace}
  \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
    \createplainmark{shorttableofconents}{both}{\shorttocname}
      \createplainmark{longtableofcontents}{both}{\longtocname}
  \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
  \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
  \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
  \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
  \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
  \createplainmark{nomenclature}{both}{\nomname}
}

\newcommand{\idxmark}[1]{{\let\gobbleone\relax\markboth{\sffamily\bfseries#1}{\sffamily\bfseries#1}}#1}
\makepagestyle{index}
\makeheadrule{index}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
% Fix for babel error by daleif (Lars Madsen}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501483/13492
\makeevenhead{index}%
{\let\gobbleone\relax\sffamily\bfseries\rightmark}%
{\sffamily\bfseries\MakeTextUppercase{\indexname}}%
{\let\gobbleone\relax\sffamily\bfseries\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{index}%
{\let\gobbleone\relax\sffamily\bfseries\rightmark}%
{\sffamily\bfseries\MakeTextUppercase{\indexname}}%
{\let\gobbleone\relax\sffamily\bfseries\leftmark}
\makeevenfoot{index}{}{\sffamily\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{index}{}{\sffamily\thepage}{}  

% Set pagstyle
\pagestyle{mypage}

%% CHAPTER STYLE:
\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{mychapter}{%
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\fontsize{58}{64}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
%
\settoheight{\midchapskip}{\chapnumfont 1}
\setlength{\midchapskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{48pt}
%
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{%
\chapnamefont\centering\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\par}
%
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
\vskip -8pt\centering \chapnumfont\thechapter} % or omit the vskip?
%
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{%
\par\nobreak\vskip \midchapskip%
\centering\rule{0.825\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}%
\newline}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\centering\chaptitlefont ##1}
}
\makeatother
% Set chapter style:
\chapterstyle{mychapter}


%% SECTIONING STYLES
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
%     sections:
\setsecheadstyle{\centering\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\setbeforesecskip{3.75ex+1ex-.2ex}
\setaftersecskip{2.35ex+.2ex}

%%%%%%%% END STYLE %%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%  BEGIN INDEXING  %%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{repeatindex}

\newcommand{\indexemph}{\textbf} % definition or main location
\newcommand{\nn}[1]{{#1}n}
\newcommand{\figidx}[1]{{#1}fig}

\providecommand\gobbleone[1]{}
\newcommand{\seeonly}[2]{\, (\emph{\seename} #1)}
\newcommand{\also}[2]{\unskip(\emph{\alsoname} #1)}
\newcommand{\Also}[2]{\unskip\emph{See also} #1}
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332093/error-with-entries-in-index-page-header-memoir-class
\makeatletter
\def\indexsee#1{\indexseeI#1@\end}
\def\indexseeI#1@#2\end{%
  \def\temp{#2}%
  \ifx\temp\empty
    \def\next{\indexseeIII{#1}{#1}}%
  \else
    \def\next{\indexseeII#1@#2\end}%
  \fi
  \next
}
\def\indexseeII#1@#2@\end{\indexseeIII{#1}{#2}}
\def\indexseeIII#1#2#3{\index{#1@#2\protect\gobbleone|seeonly{#3}}}
\newcommand{\indexalso}[2]{\index{#1!zzzz@\protect\gobbleone|also{#2}}}
\newcommand{\indexAlso}[2]{\index{#1!zzzz@\protect\gobbleone|Also{#2}}}
\makeatother
%% try this
\newcommand{\indexnamesee}[2]{\index[names]{#1\protect\gobbleone|seeonly{#2}}}
% ...fix for memoir to put hyperlink on mainref, too:
\newcommand{\mainref}[1]{\textbf{\emph{\hyperpage{#1}}}}

%%%%%%%%  END INDEXING  %%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%  CROSS-REFERENCING  %%%%%%%%
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,
  bookmarksnumbered,
  breaklinks=true,
  colorlinks, citecolor=red, filecolor=black, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue,
  linktocpage=true,linktoc=all%
}
%%%%%%%%  END CROSS-REFERENCING  %%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[draft]{fixme}%
\fxsetup{layout=margin}%
\fxusetheme{color}%

\makeindex

\begin{document}

%% !! UNCOMMENT NEXT LINE TO FORCE SIMULATED repeatindex ERROR !!
%\small

\mainmatter

\chapter{The fall of Humpty-Dumpty}
This is about the story\index{story} of Humpty-Dumpty%
\index{Humpty|see{Humpty-Dumpty}}
\index{Dumpty|see{Humpty-Dumpty}}
\index{Humpty-Dumpty|seealso{King's horses}}

\section{The Wall}

\index{bnothing}
\index{bnothing!nil}
\index{bnothing!nil!and zero}
\index{bnothing!null}
\index{bnull elements}
\index{bzero elements}
\index{belements!zero}

\index{cnothing}
\index{cnothing!nil}
\index{cnothing!nil!and zero}
\index{cnothing!null}
\index{cnull elements}
\index{czero elements}
\index{celements!zero}

\index{dnothing}
\index{dnothing!nil}
\index{dnothing!nil!and zero}
\index{dnothing!null}
\index{dnull elements}
\index{dzero elements}
\index{delements!zero}

\index{enothing}
\index{enothing!nil}
\index{enothing!nil!and zero}
\index{enothing!null}
\index{enull elements}
\index{ezero elements}
\index{eelements!zero}

\index{fnothing}
\index{fnothing!nil}
\index{fnothing!nil!and zero}
\index{fnothing!null}
\index{fnull elements}
\index{fzero elements}
\index{felements!zero}

\index{gnothing}
\index{gnothing!nil}
\index{gnothing!nil!and zero}
\index{gnothing!null}
\index{gnull elements}
\index{gzero elements}
\index{gelements!zero}

\index{hnothing}
\index{hnothing!nil}
\index{hnothing!nil!and zero}
\index{hnothing!null}
\index{hnull elements}
\index{hzero elements}
\index{helements!zero}

\section{The King's horses}

\index{knothing}
\index{knothing!nil}
\index{knothing!nil!and zero}
\index{knothing!null}
\index{knull elements}
\index{kzero elements}
\index{kelements!zero}

\index{lnothing}
\index{lnothing!nil}
\index{lnothing!nil!and zero}
\index{lnothing!null}
\index{lnull elements}
\index{lzero elements}
\index{lelements!zero}

\index{mnothing}
\index{mnothing!nil}
\index{mnothing!nil!and zero}
\index{mnothing!null}
\index{mnull elements}
\index{mzero elements}
\index{melements!zero}

\index{nnothing}
\index{nnothing!nil}
\index{nnothing!nil!and zero}
\index{nnothing!null}
\index{nnull elements}
\index{nzero elements}
\index{nelements!zero}

\backmatter

\pagestyle{index}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1em}

\printindex\cleardoublepage%

\end{document}
```

**CAUTION:** As it stands, `file.tex` processes without error despite the as-yet unaltered `.ist` needed to accommodate `repeatindex`. However, you may simulate the error with `repeatindex` simply by uncommenting the line

```
%\small
```

right after `\begin{document}`.

That artifice is the best I've been able to do so far to get a MWE exhibiting the `repeatindex` error.

I think all that `\small` accomplishes is to change which item begins and ends in each index column and page, so that this affects what `repeatindex` does when an index item does break across pages or columns.

In my actual, book-length, document, there is no such use of `\small` affecting the entire document body.

*Note:* The issue arises from the likely solution to the problem presented in [Indexing error: \mathit allowed only in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528504/indexing-error-mathit-allowed-only-in-math-mode).

Comment: Well you could try `item_0  "\n\\item [\\idxmark{"` and `delim_0 "}], "` but I have some doubts that the repeatindex code will like it that there is  your `\idxmark` inside the brackets. Due to the missing complete example I haven't tested.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Indeed,` item_0 "\n\\item [\\idxmark{"` and `delim_0 "}], "` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

repeatindex is not compatible with the memoir class as the code assumes that \subitem executes `\@idxitem` which it doesn't do in memoir.

repeatindex is buggy. It has (at least) two \expandafter to much. You can try this after loading the package, then it will at least probably not longer error.

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument
{
 % New \subitem command, to be used as usual
  \renewcommand{\subitem}{%
    % call original command
    \orig@subitem
    % set the contents to be repeated on the next page
    \expandafter\hhafterpage\expandafter{\expandafter\par\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\entryprefix\@@entry\entrypostfix}}%
    % copy \@entry to \@@entry. This is done to delay the entry to be
    % put onto the page, due to a strange behaviour of afterpage (some
    % text of the next page is executed before the afterpage text is
    % put onto the page).
    \xdef\@@entry{\@entry}%
  }%
  %
  % New \subsubitem command, to be used as usual
  \renewcommand{\subsubitem}{%
    % call original command
    \orig@subsubitem
    % set the contents to be repeated on the next page
    \expandafter\hhafterpage\expandafter{\expandafter\par\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\itshape\@@entry\dots}}%
    % copy \@entry to \@@entry. This is done to delay the entry to be
    % put onto the page, due to a strange behaviour of afterpage (some
    % text of the next page is executed before the afterpage text is
    % put onto the page).
    \xdef\@@entry{\@entry}%
  }%

}
\makeatother
```

The ist-style is buggy too. It is missing a subitem case. But as you don't use it, it won't affect you:

```
item_0 "\n  \\item ["
delim_0 "], "
% added subitem case
item_x1 "] \n \\subitem "
```

Comment: Correct, that code avoids the `repeatindex` error when used with my `.ist` (the one including a call to `\idxmark`). But what repeatindex is supposed to do is not actually being done: an item is repeated at the top of the next page or column (with a trailing ellipsis mark) if a page or column break, respectively, occurs within its list of subitems. Instead, I'm just getting an ellipsis mark at the top of every column and page after the first in the index.

Comment: yes, as I wrote: it is not compatible with memoir.